# Struggling to install sentinelsat

Tags: ubuntu, sentinel-2, pip

I am struggling to install sentinel sat. After exhausting all my options I have decided to ask if someone can just guide me in the right direction.

Firstly I tried simply:

```
sudo apt-get install sentinelsat
```

and I got this error:

```
sudo apt-get install sentinelsat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sentinelsat
```

Upon finishing some research on this I realized that it is probably because I was still running Ubuntu 17.10. So I updated my entire system and currently running Ubuntu 18.04.1.

So I thought my problem is solved. Again

```
sudo apt-get install sentinelsat
```

Same error.

I then tried to look for some tutorials on sentinelsat.

Followed the following:

https://pypi.org/project/sentinelsat/

In this tutorial is says I must use:

```
pip install sentinelsat
```

Got the following error:

```
Collecting sentinelsat
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/e1/ddf8474a77b9e8ebfd7b181c31a50df229c27ba57031fa9dfe61d7a17fe5/sentinelsat-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from sentinelsat)
Collecting tqdm (from sentinelsat)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/e0/52b2faaef4fd87f86eb8a8f1afa2cd6eb11146822033e29c04ac48ada32c/tqdm-4.25.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: click in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from sentinelsat)
Collecting geojson>=2 (from sentinelsat)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/39/231105abbfd2332f108cdbfe736e56324949fa9e80e536ae60a082cf96a9/geojson-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting html2text (from sentinelsat)
Collecting geomet (from sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sentinelsat)
Installing collected packages: tqdm, geojson, html2text, geomet, sentinelsat
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tqdm'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

As the error recommended at the last line I tried to upgrade pip:

```
    pip install --upgrade pip
```

Same error as the previous one

Running out of options I tried sudo apt-get again and did some research.

Looked at the following discussion:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt

and in this discussion it said I must check if the package actually exists.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Strangly no sentinelsat package exist according to this website.

So I am really out of options and was wondering if someone can help me.
Is the problem with my ubuntu, pip, sentinelsat I dont know.

As Ian recommended I tried to install it in a virtualenv. Activated the virtualenv successfully and got the following error:

```
jaun@jaun-pc:~/sentinelsat/bin$ cd ~/
jaun@jaun-pc:~$ pip install sentinelsat
Collecting sentinelsat
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/e1/ddf8474a77b9e8ebfd7b181c31a50df229c27ba57031fa9dfe61d7a17fe5/sentinelsat-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from sentinelsat)
Collecting tqdm (from sentinelsat)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/e0/52b2faaef4fd87f86eb8a8f1afa2cd6eb11146822033e29c04ac48ada32c/tqdm-4.25.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: click in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from sentinelsat)
Collecting geojson>=2 (from sentinelsat)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/39/231105abbfd2332f108cdbfe736e56324949fa9e80e536ae60a082cf96a9/geojson-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting html2text (from sentinelsat)
Collecting geomet (from sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sentinelsat)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->sentinelsat)
Installing collected packages: tqdm, geojson, html2text, geomet, sentinelsat
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/jaun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tqdm'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pip error has nothing to do with the version of pip, and every thing to do with permissions. By default pip will try to install into a system directory where all users can see it. While this may be fine on a windows box under linux it fails because you don't have permission to write there, hence the actual error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tqdm
```

So you can either install it as root (bad idea) or install in a virtual environment (much better idea):

```
virtualenv sentinelsat
cd sentinelsat
. ./bin/activate
pip install sentinelsat
```

should do it, certainly works on my Ubuntu 16.04 box.

Comment: Hi Ian. Thanks for the quick response. I have done exactly that without any luck. Got the same error.

Comment: did the virtual environment start up correctly?

Comment: Yes sir it did. I had to install it first on my system. Thereafter activated it and in that directory tried to install without any luck.

Comment: is it exactly the same error?

Comment: Ian I have edited my original question for your information. It does seem as though there is some slight difference. I am also trying to figure out what this error mean. I do appreciate the help

Comment: Ian out of frustration, I installed it as the root which you have warned me against. Would you mind to explain to me why this is a bad option

Comment: Because the next package you install will probably want a different incompatible version of one of those dependencies and python is not bright enough to work with that.